# live elements, bind and trigger

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have this code here:

```
$('#packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx').bind('check', function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
$('#packageStatus').live('change', function(){
    $('#packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx').trigger('check');
});
```

Both of the elements are live, so I'm getting this error on line 5:

```
$("#packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx") is null
```

How do I work around this? Basically what I need is that when a select #packageStatus changes, a checkbox #packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx is being checked.

Any help?

Comment: you should *never* get that error, are you including Prototype on the page too?

Comment: Yes, I'm including jquery just before I'm including this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx').bind('check', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
$('#packageStatus').live('change', function(e){

    $('#packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx').trigger('check');
});
```

But please post your HTML as well.. I can not see how your first function is triggered twice.
Also, why use 'live'. Can't see that from your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post HTML, because this is proprietary software I'm trying to modify and the source code is encoded. I've only got access to the <head> bit where all the js files are inserted. Also, the elements are generated live - I'm not sure exactly how though. And with this code I'm getting the same error as before on the same line. It's probably because it's a live element. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx').bind('check', function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
$('#packageStatus').live('change', function(){
    $('#packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: This `.attr('checked', 'checked');` won't trigger a custom event.

Comment: the last line of the question stated he only wanted to check the checkbox. `Basically what I need is that when a select #packageStatus changes, a checkbox #packageDateStopRenewalCheckedx is being checked.`

Comment: the problem is though, that I can't get to #packageDateStopRenewalChecked at this point. It returns null.